# Create Series of Families On a Selected Path In Revit Using Dynamo

Tags: autodesk, revit-api, revit

I’ve started exploring dynamo for a while now and quite enjoying its power. I’ve started work on a project, I’m wondering if someone would like to share their expert views on how do I create series of families from one starting point to other. See the following image to understand it visually. I’m sure we can achieve such functionality via Dynamo. Appreciate any help. Thank you.
 [image]

[image]

Comment: This is really a Dynamo question, rather than SO/programming question. Please post to Dynamo Forum: https://forum.dynamobim.com/ You will get much better help there. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a discussion of using a [dynamic model updater DMU](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.31) in conjunction with the [`Idling` event](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.28) to achieve a couple of complex synchronisation tasks, including a video of almost exactly what you are asking for: [Updater Queues Multi-Transaction Operation for Idling](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/11/updater-queues-multi-transaction-operation-for-idling.html).